# Run ASPX page for every 15 secs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, global-asax

I need to call an ASPX page every 15 seconds. That page will receive data through the request and update a table in the database.

I have below a sample table for auction data.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
AID           STARTDATE               ENDDATE
-------------------------------------------------------------
1             18-7-2013 12:00 PM     20-7-2013 12:00 PM
2             19-7-2013 12:00 PM     21-7-2013 12:00 PM
3             19-7-2013 01:00 PM     21-7-2013 12:00 PM
4             19-7-2013 01:00 PM     22-7-2013 12:00 PM
```

We need to check in our database and send a web request for all records which are presently in auction mode (the current date and time between the `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE`). Sometimes 3 or 4 items will start their auction at same time. How do we handle this scenario?

What is the best way to get an update every 15 seconds for all items which are currently in running auction mode and store in our database?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Sree, how will you be calling the ASPX page (if you know)? Do you control the ASPX page as well, or is it provided by another party? Does it need to be an ASPX page? Could you provide a little more information on what data you need to update every 15 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a client-side solution, you can use the JavaScript `setInterval()` function, like this:

```
var ResInterval = window.setInterval('myAjaxCall()', 15000); // 15 seconds
var myAjaxCall = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'YourPage.aspx/MyMethod',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(xml) {
            // Put logic here when data comes back from server
        }
};
```

Note: The `url` can be whatever is script callable (web service, `WCF` service, `ASP.NET AJAX Page Method`, etc.).

To stop the interval, do this:

```
window.clearInterval(resInterval);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you simple need to automatically reload your ASPX page every 15 seconds, just add a meta tag to page header:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quartz.NET Scheduling Framework for .NET Platform which is like Windows Task Scheduler but a lot better.

Project site: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Nuget package: http://nuget.org/packages/Quartz/